# sourced vs executed scripts: in which shell process do they run?

Tags: linux, shell

This is all in ubuntu using the terminal.

When sourcing a file after first creating it, you would need `read` permissions first?

Then to execute you need `executable` permissions so it would show `x` when 
using `ls -l filename`?

What im not sure of is what process executes the contents when you source? Would it be `current shell`?

Then when you execute the script calling the name of the file you would be using `new shell` process?

Starting to learn Linux so trying to understand the permissions and processes of scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a little experiment;

```
$ echo $$ # print PID of current shell
1234
$ echo 'echo $$' > test.sh # make a little shell script that just prints its PID
$ ls -l test.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hlub hlub 10 Sep 26 20:01 test.sh
# no x'es: not executable
$ source test.sh # source it....
1234
# OK, that worked, even without execute permission, 
# .... and we get the same PID: 
# .... apparently "source" runs commands in the current shell
$ ./test.sh
zsh: permission denied: ./test.sh
# Oops! need execute permission
$ chmod a+x test.sh # make the script executable
$ ls -l test.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 hlub hlub 10 Sep 26 20:02 test.sh
# x'es, just as I expected!
$ ./test.sh
5678
# OK, so now the script executes in a new process!
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes a lot of sense now!

Comment: Very clearly put! Thank you ❤️